# Django slugify - UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: python, django

Изучаю Django и мне необходимо чтобы в приложении с рецептами можно было создавать рецепты с одинаковыми названиями.

Изначально slugify был записан вот так:

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        return super().save()
```

но тогда при создании рецепта с таким же названием я получаю ошибку **UNIQUE constraint failed**

Я пытался добавлять к ссылке дату публикации или id, но в обоих случаях получаю link-**none**

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title) + "-" + str(self.pub_date)
        return super().save()
```

Текущий код **models.py**

```py
class Recipe(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='recipes',
        verbose_name='Автор'
    )
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, verbose_name='Название'
    )
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='recipes/', verbose_name='Изображение'
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='Описание'
    )
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(
        Ingredient, through='RecipeIngredient',
        through_fields=('recipe', 'ingredient')
    )
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(
        Tag, verbose_name='Теги'
    )
    duration = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1)],
        verbose_name='Время приготовления в минутах'
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(
        unique=True, verbose_name='Путь'
    )
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, blank=True,
        null=True, verbose_name='Дата публикации'
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pub_date',)
        verbose_name = 'Рецепт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Рецепты'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title) + "-" + str(self.pub_date)
        return super().save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pub_date` заполняется во время `save`, а значит значение недоступно, до того, как вызовется `save` у модели.

Можно сделать так:

```
import time

self.slug = slugify(self.title + "-" + str(time.time()))
```

Comment: Спасибо. Не подумал сначала сохранить. Вот такой вариант тоже заработал:

```python
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save()
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title) + "-" + str(self.id)
            self.save()
```